# What are people's thoughts about rel="canonical"? Is anyone using it?

Tags: seo

I just received a memo (dated Feb 29) from our pals at Mountain View. Apparently they want us to [start using another tag to specify canonical urls](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html).

As someone who builds a fair amount of websites, this obviously intrigued me, but I was curious to know if anybody else had started using it? Is anybody planning to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's interesting for Wikipedia which intends to have all alternative URLs indexed, e.g. `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_language` has canonical URL `/wiki/Python_(programming_language)`.

It might also be useful for paged or sorted content, e.g. `/foobar?sorby=date` with canonical `/foobar`.

Personally I just prefer to exclude all non-preferred versions of pages from index by adding `robots.txt` rules (in case of Google it's simple, because it accepts regular expressions there) and `<meta robots>`. It saves me bandwidth, and the result is probably the same.

Comment: The robots.txt approach isn't scalable up to something like Wikipedia's redirects - they have hundreds of thousands if not millions of them, and they can't be easily wildcarded.

Answer (score 1):

It's useful if you have a case-insensitive web server, since links into http://my.site.com/foo.html and http://my.site.com/FOO.html would be treated as two seperate documents by search engines (thus reducing that document's page-rank)

Of course, you can get around this with a 301 redirect to the lower-cased version, but using rel=canonical means your users have 1 less HTTP request to make.

Answer (score 1):

I'm already using the Content-Location header correctly. I won't be in any hurry to implement Google's new "standard".

Comment: Sadly Google said that too many people were using it incorerctly and they are deliberately ignoring this header :/ Which I think is short-sighted, because in time lots of people will use rel=canonical incorrectly and they'll have to fix this data anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple versions of the same content (maybe a print view, or different sort orders) then it seems to be very handy.  I've used it on a couple pages - haven't got any data to show its impact yet though.